# Convert Double to Currency after calculations

Tags: c#, double, currency

I have all but finished this code but I am not sure it will work yet. But the last thing I need before i try to execute the program to work is to convert a double I created to calculate discounts to currency to output to a label. Here is my code..

```
   private void btnCharacteristicsContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int intStudentClass = lstClass.SelectedIndex;
        int intParkingSpace = lstNeedsCampusParking.SelectedIndex;
        double dblParkingDiscount;
        double dblFinalParking;
        if (lstNeedsCampusParking.SelectedIndex.ToString() == ("No"))
        {
            dblFinalParking = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (intStudentClass)
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    dblParkingDiscount = 300;
                    if (lstLiveOnCampus.SelectedIndex.ToString() == ("Yes"))
                    {
                        dblFinalParking = dblParkingDiscount * .25;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dblFinalParking = dblParkingDiscount;
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                case 3:
                    dblParkingDiscount = 300 * .1;
                    if (lstLiveOnCampus.SelectedIndex.ToString() == ("Yes"))
                    {
                        dblFinalParking = dblParkingDiscount * .25;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dblFinalParking = dblParkingDiscount;
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    dblParkingDiscount = 300 * .2;
                    if (lstLiveOnCampus.SelectedIndex.ToString() == ("Yes"))
                    {
                        dblFinalParking = dblParkingDiscount * .25;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dblFinalParking = dblParkingDiscount;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            lblCharacteristicsOutput.Text = dblFinalParking;      
        }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString

Comment: Just a note: You can remove braces around string literals. `"Yes"` instead of `("Yes")`

Comment: I'd *strongly* recommend against using double here to start with. Decimal is a much more appropriate type for currency values.

Comment: You should avoid hungarian notation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933/why-shouldnt-i-use-hungarian-notation) - you're probably going to change your double type to decimal - are you going to rename all your variables too?

Answer (score 1):

dear you just need to :

```
lblCharacteristicsOutput.Text = dblFinalParking.ToString("C2");
```

it will automatically convert amount to US Standard. for example:
this = `3401402.7` to
this = `$3,401,402.70`
also it will round to 2 precision and if we have 1 decimal after point it will automatically return 2 points after point.

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this

```
lblCharacteristicsOutput.Text = dblFinalParking.ToString("C0");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `System.Decimal` instead of `System.Double` for currency, there are quite a few other entries that go into more details. Here are a few examples.

[In .net, how do I choose between a Decimal and a Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545567/in-net-how-do-i-choose-between-a-decimal-and-a-double)

[decimal vs double! - Which one should I use and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)