# When converting double to string, how can I round it up to N decimal places in C#?

Tags: c#, number-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-significant-figures-after-decimal-point)

I need *at most* N decimals, no more, but I don't want trailing zeroes. For example, if N = 2 then

> 15.352
>   15.355
>   15.3
>   15

should become (respectively)

> 15.35
>   15.36
>   15.3
>   15

Comment: Do you want a third digit of "5" to *always* round up, or round to even?

Comment: Out of interest, what do these numbers represent? It's possible that you should be using `decimal` instead of `double` to start with.

Comment: They are values which I use either to draw a graph or display in a table. Additionally I perform some operations on sets of these numbers to get hourly, daily, weekly (etc.) averages, maximums, minimums or totals and then use those values on the graph/table. When drawing a graph I always use `double`, but placing, for example, an averaged value as it is in a table creates an unreadable mess of digits, which is why I need to format them in this way (and each column needs to round to a different number of digits).

Comment: But what are the values actually representing? Height? Money?

Comment: Currently they're temperatures, percentages (e.g. moisture), amount of rain in a given period, etc. But they can be anything you can put on a graph.

Comment: There's a big difference though - temperature makes sense to store in a double, but financial values really *shouldn't* be stored in a double, even though you can put them on a graph...

Comment: Thanks. I looked up why (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803225/when-should-i-use-double-instead-of-decimal)). I'll keep that in mind if I need to graph anything to do with finances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `Math.Round(value, 2).ToString()`

```
Math.Round(15.352, 2).ToString();  //15.35
Math.Round(15.355, 2).ToString();  //15.36
Math.Round(15.3, 2).ToString();    //15.3
Math.Round(15.0, 2).ToString();    //15
```

The second paramater for round is for you to specify how many decimal places to round to. It will round up by default.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by using a custom format string, such as "0.##", which displays a maximum two decimal places.

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
```

Reference: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: Yes, that does the job for N = 2, but I was hoping there was a way to convert to string for any N. Using, for example double.ToString("N" + X.ToString()), where X is int, will do this, but will also add trailing zeroes which I don't want.

Comment: @NikolaNovak is it possible to use decimal instead of double in your case? If so, you can use Decimal.Round(Decimal, Int32) method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6be1edhb.aspx

Comment: See my exchange with Jon Skeet in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Google does lead the way: Use ## to skip leading zeros in your format string.

```
// max. two decimal places
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4567);      // "123.46"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.4);         // "123.4"
String.Format("{0:0.##}", 123.0);         // "123"
```