# Still not displaying $

Tags: c#, label

Can someone please help me by reviewing why the label on visual studio is not displaying currency? Any help is appreciated.

```
double hours = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
double rate = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
double grosspay = hours * rate;

string.Format("{0:c}", label9.Text);
label9.Text = grosspay.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you want to assign the result of string.Format to your label text

```
label9.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", grosspay)
```

But working with currency values is usually done using the decimal datatype

```
decimal hours = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
decimal rate = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
decimal grosspay = hours * rate;
label9.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", grosspay)
```

[When should I use double instead of decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803225/when-should-i-use-double-instead-of-decimal)