# MySQL - Decimal(M,D) vs Double(M,D)

Tags: mysql, sql

Well, I know this question has been asked several times.. But, I still don't get a satisfied explanation, especially on why we **MUST** use `Decimal` for monetary purpose.. As far as I know,

1. `Decimal` can save larger number than `Double`
2. `Decimal` stores exact value and `Double` store approx. value

So, can anyone explain and maybe give some actual result in query about,

1. What do they mean by exact value and approx. value?
2. Why should I use `Decimal` for monetary purpose ?

Currently I'm using `Double(15,2)` as it gives enough precision for my boss. Besides I ran some test in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03aead/1) and I don't see any precision issue..

TESTED QUERY:

```
create table test(
  value1 Decimal(15,4),
  value2 Double(15,4)
  );

insert into test values(0.0001, 0.0001),
                       (123.123, 123.123), 
                       (0.0000001, 0.0000001);

select sum(value1), sum(value2) from test
```

RESULT

```
SUM(VALUE1) SUM(VALUE2)
123.1231    123.1231
```

Comment: If you can't make it happen now, it doesn't mean that it won't happen in the future. If you stick to DOUBLE, be prepared for rounding errors.

Comment: There is similar questions here on SO. In terms of monetary operations, check __comments__ to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1165788/2637490) - and linked question, such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803225/when-should-i-use-double-instead-of-decimal) as well

Comment: @Naktibalda Well, that's one reason that people keep mentioning, but no one really gives a good example..

Comment: insert something like 0.75 * 0.2 and check (not 0.15 directly)

Comment: Well, in my case your argument is not valid, check [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c81442/1).. If it's wrong approach, then share you fiddle pls.