# Why result of % operator for double differ from decimal?

Tags: c#, double, decimal

Why outputs for these types aren't equal in this case?

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", 0.3d % 0.1d); // 0.1
Console.WriteLine("{0}", 0.3m % 0.1m); // 0.0
```

Comment: Floating point representations? (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803225/when-should-i-use-double-instead-of-decimal)

Comment: You should get an answer when you tell us what is the difference between double and decimal value types.