# Datatype for for value of 20 000 000,50 in C#?

Tags: c#

If I need to present value that is

```
20 000 000,50
12 000 000
 2 000 000,75
   100 000,866
18 000 000,42
```

What datatype for C# should I use?

Comment: To clarify - is the `,` the decimal separator in your locale?

Comment: Is this one value or 5 different value? 2., 3. and 4. examples have leading white spaces?

Comment: you need to present pairs of numbers or it's a big number?

Comment: Have you tried to use one of the available types? If so, why the question? Did you encounter a problem? Did you try to type the "string" as-is, with the incorrect decimal? In which case this is a parsing problem?

Comment: James, yes it is in my locale

Comment: is double not precise enough?

Comment: I dont know what datatype is relevant ofr instane is it decimal, float etc. I need a datatype that can retrieve a high value

Comment: @thumbmunkeys a double is never precise enough due to rounding errors. Which is why people use decimal. This is a *small* number though. The question doesn't make sense as is

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's why I asked

Comment: @HelloWorld just check the documentation then, the limits are described. Although 20M is **not** a high value. In any case, you **can't** use 20000000,50 as a decimal or double literal, you should use 20000000.50 or 20000000.50m

Comment: Which datatypes have you tried? And why don't they work for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use double instead of decimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803225/when-should-i-use-double-instead-of-decimal)

Answer (score 4):

So you're working with *floating point* values. You have two options:

1. Double
2. Decimal

Use `Double` if you are given *significant digits*, e.g. `2000000.50` actually means, say, `2.00e6` (3 significant digits). Usuallly these kinds of values are from physical world: *volts*, *ampers*, *meters*, etc.

Use `Decimal` if you are given *significant digits after decimal point*, e.g. `2000000.50` actually means `2000000.500` (3 digits *after the decimal point*).
Usually these kinds of values are from finance: *dollars and cents* etc.

Comment: +1. Exactly: the correct data type depends on the meaning of the handled values, which is something that the OP has not specified.

Answer (score 2):

You should use decimal.

Here is the description of decimal in MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

Here is the difference from double:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/decimal-vs-double-difference?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: `decimal`.

The alternative - `double` is not preferred for monetary values because the cents are binary encoded and frequently the values are rounded (e.g. instead of `100.04` you may have `100.03999999`).

Comment: Explaining the reason why would make your answer better, though.

Comment: From MSDN: "The decimal keyword indicates a 128-bit data type. Compared to floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary calculations.". Decimal have 28-29 significant digits. That's why this type is the most suitable in this case.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi The question is not "why" but "which" datatype. The alternative - `double` is not preferred for monetary values because the cents are binary encoded and frequently the values are rounded (e.g. instead of 100.04 you may have 100.03999999). There is enough explanations about differences and which is better for specific purposes.

Comment: @i486 Since your comment was the most useful part of your post, I have edited it in.

Answer (score 1):

We used decimal too.

> decimal = 128-bit precise decimal values with 28-29 significant
>   digits,
>   double =   64-bit double-precision floating point type,
>   float =   32-bit single-precision floating point type,
>   int = 32-bit
>   signed integer type