# HQL Return DOUBLE Value in select NHIBERNATE

Tags: c#, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this query, and it should return double (that is in database as `Decimal(10,2)`):

```
public products SearchPrice(string nmproduct)
        {
            string hql = "select x.custo from products x where x.nmproduct = ?";
            IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
            query.SetParameter(0, nmproduct);
            return query.UniqueResult<products>();
        }
```

I want to get the price in database.

The exception is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'Administrative.Models.products'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting a decimal value to your entity, you need to use:

```
query.UniqueResult<decimal>()
```

When you represent money, you need to use `decimal` instead `double` for not to lose accuracy, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/803270/1486443).

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem. Just needed to change to decimal.

`public decimal SearchPrice(string nmproduct)
        {
            string hql = "select x.custo from products x where x.nmproduct = ?";
            IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
            query.SetParameter(0, nmproduct);
            return query.UniqueResult<decimal>();
        }`