# Compare 2 prices as datatype string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, type-conversion, currency

I am wondering how i would compare 2 Prices as datatype string.

Example;

```
string oldPrice = "£1.99";
string newPrice = "£2.50";
```

I want to compare if the newPrice is >= to oldPrice but im unsure how to convert the string into a decimal/int. Taking off the £ sign.

Any ideas? hints or tips on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
string oldPrice = "£1.99";

decimal result = decimal.Parse(oldPrice, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);
```

Storing currency as a `double` is **not** a good idea, and it would be better to use `decimal` instead. The decimal type is only more accurate at representing base 10 numbers (e.g. those used in currency/financial calculations). In general, the double type is going to offer at least as great precision and definitely greater speed for arbitrary real numbers.
Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803225/when-should-i-use-double-instead-of-decimal) links for more information where and when to use `decimal` or `double`.

Also check out @Triynko's comment from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when):

> Here's why you use Decimal for money: Double's accuracy is only 16
>   decimal digits, and after just a few arithmetic ops, errors will
>   quickly accumulate large enough to creep into the 15, 14, 13, etc.
>   digits. Rounding to "cents" requires at least one digit of full
>   accuracy after cents digit, but really you should reserve 4 or 5 to
>   insulate from cumulative arithmetic errors, which you CANNOT allow to
>   corrupt the hundredths column you use to round the cents. That leaves
>   you with 16 (total) - 2 (cents) - (4 or 5 error padding) = oh $hit
>   only 7 (or less) reliable integer digits for your money!

Comment: Why is not a good idea storing currency as double? Maybe you should explain that in your answer :)

Comment: @Pikoh I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when) will answer to your question.

Comment: I know the answer SeM. I was suggesting you to explain that in your answer to complete it

Comment: @SeM - it's best that you edit your answer to include the reason for using `decimal` and then add to it also the link

Answer (score 3):

```
if(decimal.Parse(newPrice, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency) >= decimal.Parse(oldPrice, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency)){
  //    Do something here
}
```

Whilst you can also use `double.Parse(...)` it is not a good idea to store currency in a float as they are actually stored as base-2 numbers, whereas we care about base-10 numbers when we’re talking about money. Therefore they cannot represent some decimal values, so they round in ways you don’t expect. The last thing you want when performing maths on currency values is to lose money due to rounding!

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803225/when-should-i-use-double-instead-of-decimal) for a more detailed explanation.