# Substracting leads to an error and I don`t know how to fix it C#

Tags: c#

For my school assignment, I have to do a cinema ticketing pool that calculates the prices, discounts, taxes etc.
I need to show the Total, the discount and then the total after Discount.
Im trying to do the total - the discount to get that answer but it wont let me and im out of ideas to fix this error.

Here is the code:

```
GroupLbl.Text = "Total discount: " + ((Kids * Price) * 0.75 + (Adults * Price) + (Seniors * Price) * 0.5) * 0.1;
DiscountLbl.Text = "Total after discount: " +TotalLbl.Text - GroupLbl.Text;
```

> Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Anyone knows the problem?

Comment: Welcome - dont post pics, post code .. post the error, post what you tried

Comment: Just FYI, "it wont let me" is not a good explanation of what the problem is.

Comment: As this is your first post, I advise you to see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example, instead of a pic you should be posting your relevant code and any exception text it is throwing at you

Comment: Well, imagine that we have `string a = "abcd";` and `string b = "123";` what result do you expect from `string c = a - b;`, please?

Comment: What part of the error is confusing you? It tells you that you can't subtract two strings. Where is your actual problem? You already have code that converts strings to numbers so I assume its not that. Is it just that you don't understand why you need to convert to numbers before subtracting things? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are trying to substract strings,which is not possible and is not what you want. Your substract operation must be done using the proper type, in this case probably `decimal`. So you must parse the string values to decimal,substract them and then, convert the result to string to display it. You should be doing something like this:

```
DiscountLbl.Text= "Total after discount: " 
                + (decimal.Parse(TotalLbl.Text) - decimal.Parse(GroupLbl.Text)).ToString();
```

**Edit**

As Steve and BviLLe_Kid pointed out, as the input comes from a user and it could contain wrong values, you must be using `TryParse` instead of `Parse`. So the code would look like this:

```
decimal total;
decimal group;

if (decimal.TryParse(TotalLbl.Text,out total) && decimal.TryParse(GroupLbl.Text,out group))
{
     string DiscountLbl = "Total after discount: " + (total-group).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Like what Steve said below in a comment, depending on what the user is typing in (can you really trust them? :) ) you might want to use `.TryParse`

Comment: Yes,I was trying not to give the exact solution to OP so he could maybe find that problem and had to work it out ;). But, of course...in every user input you should use `TryParse`

Comment: haha sorry for ruining your hidden egg!

Comment: No problem @BviLLe_Kid, you were right anyway. i edited my answer ;)

Comment: Looking at the code that the OP just posted, `decimal.Parse(GroupLbl.Text)` will *always* fail because it'll contain something like "Total Discount: 10.2".

Comment: You are right @EJoshuaS. My second code won't fail as it use `TryParse`, but won't also get the desired result. But that's a different problem and I think OP should deal with it,

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string to an int before subtraction.
Use something like `int x = Convert.ToInt32(theString)`.

Comment: Might want to cast to decimal to keep the decimal point, for dollars and cents.. since we are talking about currency.  Int's would just strictly be dollars.

Comment: True - but we don't want to do the kids homework for him!

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast text to double

```
DiscountLabel.Text = "Total after discount:" + (Convert.ToDouble(TotalLbl.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(GroupLbl.Text)).ToString();
```

Comment: Speaking about currency, the proper type should be `decimal` instead of `double`. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/803225/579895) for example

Comment: @Pikoh You are right decimal is better

Comment: also considering it's a user input, you should probably TryParse

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
//Since you are dealing with decimals:
string strResult = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have indicated, you need to convert your strings to integers before you can subtract.

Also, as a general rule, pay close attention to the error message:

> Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

In this case, the problem is exactly what the compiler says: '-' can't be applied to strings.

Keep in mind that certain operations are only meaningful for certain types. Consider a few examples of edge cases if you try to do arithmetic on strings:

- "abc" - "c" (presumably, this means "string difference," in which
  case the result should be "ab")
- "10" + "20": this is ambiguous because it could mean either "1020"
  (string concatenation) or "30" (arithmetic addition). In reality, the compiler will always interpret this as concatenation and the result will be "1020".
- "abc" - "def" (if this is string difference, the result should be "abc")
- "abc" * "def": No clue what this means. Think about how the compiler would interpret this (it can't). This really should be a compile error, but it's not obvious how the compiler could "know" that it should be in the general case.

As you can see, when you try to do arithmetic operations on strings, there's no general way for the compiler to figure out what you intended to do. This is especially the case given that there are hard limits on the ability to reason about programs in an automated way (see, for example, the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)).

One more thing - look at the value of `GroupLbl.Text`:

```
GroupLbl.Text = "Total discount: " + ((Kids * Price) * 0.75 + (Adults * Price) + (Seniors * Price) * 0.5) * 0.1;
```

This'll be something like "Total Discount: 10.0". What does "10.0" - "Total Discount: 10.0" mean? You're better off storing the total discount in a separate double or decimal variable.

```
double discount = ((Kids * Price) * 0.75 + (Adults * Price) + (Seniors * Price) * 0.5) * 0.1;
GroupLbl.Text = "Total discount: " + discount.ToString();
double totalAfterDiscount = double.Parse(TotalLbl.Text) - discount;
DiscountLbl.Text = "Total after discount: " + totalAfterDiscount.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to minus two label controls that contain text (some of which is numerical, which I take from the image is what you want). You cannot do that.