# Double addition does not return expected value, why?

Tags: c#

I expect `result` and `result2` to be the same:

multiplying `.1 x 10` should equal `.1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1 + .1` when running following code snippt of C#.

```
public void DoubleAddition()
    {
        Double x = .1;
        Double result = 10 * x;
        Double result2 = x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x + x;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", result, result2);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:R} - {1:R}", result, result2);
    }
```

But the output of `Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", result, result2);` is **`1 - 1`**
And When is used round-trip formater e.g. `Console.WriteLine("{0:R} - {1:R}", result, result2);` then the result was **`1 - 0.999999999999999989`**

Why is `result2` not exactly is `1` when we display using round-trip formater?
What is the value stored in memory when we declared `Double d = 0.1`?

Comment: If you want the behaviour you're talking about: use `decimal`, not `double`. How IEEE floating points round is ... not that - and if you *expect* that, then that is an error of your expectation. If you replace `double` with `decimal` and `.1` with `.1M`, I strongly suspect it will all work as you expect.

Comment: http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

Comment: [Let me just cart out the obligatory...](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: I'd also read [When should I use double instead of decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803225/when-should-i-use-double-instead-of-decimal) which goes into details from what Marc was saying