# In C#, what data type should I use to store a list of numbers with standard deviation?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm performing some tests and I have a list of values with errors of the form:

```
12.7 ± 0.3
14.2 ± 0.1
70.8 ± 0.5
```

I need to keep the standard deviation alongside the value, as I need to use it for various calculations later on.

At the moment I'm just using

```
List<KeyValuePair<double, double>>
```

But are there any better solution?

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution that suggests you need a better solution?

Comment: Better *how*?  In what respect?  Your solution looks just fine.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this. Another option would be to create a class and use `List<NumberWithStandardDeviation>`, but that might be overkill.

Comment: I would probably create a specific struct for `ValueAndStandardDeviation` - it's not really a `KeyValuePair here`; using `KeyValuePair` doesn't express the meaning of the values as clearly, IMO.

Comment: It's fine like that. You don't need anything else that what you are already using.

Comment: Is double precise enough for your purposes? because floating point arithmetic can be messy.

Comment: SO isn't the place to discuss _data structures_. [ask]

Comment: If performance or memory is/are your measures, some things to consider - what you want to establish is the quantity of entries you expect. Frequency of loading and reading data - how you anticipate accessing the data?

Comment: One option using value tuple. `List<(dobule Value, double Error)>`

Comment: There is complex data type, not sure whether u can use it.

Answer (score 5):

If the values are not going to change I would go with struct.  You can add logic (but you can do that with a class also). Go decimal unless you specifically need double.

```
public struct StdDev
{
    public decimal Val { get; }
    public decimal Dev { get; }
    public decimal Max { get { return Val + Dev; } }
    public decimal Min { get { return Val - Dev; } }
    public bool IsInDev (decimal val)
    {
        return val >= Min && val <= Max;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Val} +- {Dev}";
    }
    public StdDev (decimal val, decimal dev)
    {
        Val = val;
        Dev = dev;
    }
}
```

You could override Equals and GetHashCode.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other options to what you currently have:

It's up to you to choose and use what is convinient. Don't know if performance is what you are looking for.

Option 1 (if you are using C# 7.0 or later):

How about [Tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples)?

You won't have key value pair in tuple but rather items.

Option 2:
Like Dan wilson mentioned in the comment to your question make a class with value and error

```
public class ValueWithDeviation
{
    public double Value {get; set;}

    public double Deviation {get; set;}
}
```

Then you could have `IEnumerable<ValueWithError>`

Comment: Based on @Konamiman 's link to "a class or a struct", it might be better to design this as a struct. As a side effect the ValueWithError values (pun intended) become immutable.

Comment: Error is not the best name for deviation.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting explicitly that option 1 requires C# 7.0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

As DanWilson and Cybercop suggest, I'd say that creating a dedicated type ([a class or a struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)) is the way to go, because the value with the deviation can be seen together as a logical object. Also, that will make your life easier when you want to display the values, as you will just need to override the `ToString` method in your type.

As for the underlying type, it might be more convenient for you [to use decimal instead of double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803225/when-should-i-use-double-instead-of-decimal), but that depends on your specific project/needs.