# Double Precision

Tags: c#, double, precision

I have a code, and I do not understand it. I am developing an application which precision is very important. but it does not important for .NET, why? I don't know.

```
double value = 3.5;
MessageBox.Show((value + 1 * Math.Pow(10, -20)).ToString());
```

but the message box shows: 3.5
Please help me, Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566958/double-precision-problems-on-c-net

Comment: There is no `double` value that is exactly equal to 3.50000000000000000001.  The closest double to that number is 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have precision, but it depends on what else you want to do. If you put the following in a Console application:

```
double a = 1e-20;
Console.WriteLine(" a  = {0}", a);
Console.WriteLine("1+a = {0}", 1+a);

decimal b = 1e-20M;
Console.WriteLine(" b  = {0}", b);
Console.WriteLine("1+b = {0}", 1+b);
```

You will get

```
 a  = 1E-20
1+a = 1
 b  = 0,00000000000000000001
1+b = 1,00000000000000000001
```

But Note that The `Pow` function, like almost everything in the Math class, only takes doubles:

```
double Pow(double x, double y);
```

So you cannot take the Sine of a decimal (other then by converting it to double)

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803225/when-should-i-use-double-instead-of-decimal).

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing anything where precision is very important, you need to be aware of the limitations of floating point. A good reference is [David Goldberg's "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

You may find that floating-point doesn't give you enough precision and you need to work with a decimal type. These, however, are always much slower than floating point -- it's a tradeoff between accuracy and speed.

Comment: Good article, but it's a little hard for non-mathematicians to read.  This one's somewhat easier reading for code monkeys:  http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2):

Or use the [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(VS.71).aspx) type rather than double.

Comment: But you can't use Math.Pow() on decimals

Comment: 10^-20 can easily be given as a constant. No need to invoke Math.Pow() here.

Answer (score 2):

The precision of a `Double` is 15 digits (17 digits internally). The value that you calculate with `Math.Pow` is correct, but when you add it to `value` it just is too small to make a difference.

Edit:
A Decimal can handle that precision, but not the calculation. If you want that precision, you need to do the calculation, then convert each value to a `Decimal` before adding them together:

```
double value = 3.5;
double small = Math.Pow(10, -20);

Decimal result = (Decimal)value + (Decimal)small;

MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

Comment: but what should I do with this number?

Comment: A Decimal has that precision, but you have to do the calculation as double, then convert each to Decimal before adding them. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Double precision means it can hold 15-16 digits. 3.5 + 1e-20 = 21 digits. It cannot be represented in double precicion. You can use another type like decimal.

Comment: 15-16 digits total. The floating point can be anywhere before, after or inbetween these digits