# Simple C# calculation - datatypes

Tags: c#

Problably an easy questions but this calculation bothers me.. why is `double test = 57.05 - 57` equal to 0.049999999999997158 and not 0.05? And which datatype should I use to get the correct result?

Comment: but from an *engineering* point of view, this is an error of 0.000000000005 percent, and should be close enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `decimal`.  And read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

Comment: Instead of "Very" I would say "Vitally"

Answer (score 4):

Try to convert .05 decimal to binary and tell me what result you get (hint: it's a repeating value).

Answer (score 2):

Long answer: [Floating Point Representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

Short answer: types like double conform to IEEE 754, which dictates data types which may have a decimal point anywhere (floating).  Because of the representation in the computer's native binary, the result of mathematical operations on these representations in many cases may only be an approximation of the actual result.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point calculations are not as correct.

How about [double-precision-problems-on-c-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566958/double-precision-problems-on-c-net)