# Comparing a Single to a Double in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Here's my test code:

```
Dim testSingle As Single = 7.2
Dim testSingleF As Single = 7.2F
Dim testDouble As Double = 7.2

If testSingle = testDouble Then ' this is false
    Label1.Text = "true"
Else
    Label1.Text = "false"
End If

If testSingleF = testDouble Then ' this is false
    Label2.Text = "true"
Else
    Label2.Text = "false"
End If

If testSingle = 7.2F Then ' this is true
    Label3.Text = "true"
Else
    Label3.Text = "false"
End If
```

As you can see by my comments, the first two statements are false, and the third is true.
Why is that?  The precision shouldn't matter as it's such a small number.

What's going on here?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566958/double-precision-problems-on-net/566983#566983](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566958/double-precision-problems-on-net/566983#566983)

Comment: Thanks.  I searched for the answer, but not knowing the true nature of the problem, I didn't find this as I was barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, precision matters *even though* it is a small number. Why? Because 7.2 has an infinite number of digits in binary notation: `7.2` (dec) = `111.001100110011...` (bin) -- just like 10/3 = 3.333... in decimal notation.

Thus, `Single` and `Double` are bad choices if you need to accurately represent non-integer numbers. You have the following options:

- Use `Double`, but never compare numbers for absolute equality `a = b`. Instead, check if `Abs(a-b)` is smaller than some small threshold.
- Use the `Decimal` data type, which has been created exactly for this purpose. In a nutshell, it stores `72` (which can be represented exactly in binary) plus the information that there is one digit at the right of the decimal point. Thus, these problems don't occur here (at least not for numbers which can be represented accurately in decimal notation. 10/3 is still a problem here...)

Further information can be found, for example, on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding).

Comment: Excellent explaination, Heinzi!