# Are there any "type" on Borland C++ Builder like "decimal" from C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, decimal, c++builder

In C#, there is a type called `decimal` (the System.Decimal structure). I have found information that shows how it is better than `float` and `double` types for some cases:

- [StackOverflow - double-precision-problems-on-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566958/double-precision-problems-on-net)
- [StackOverflow - how-to-make-doubles-work-properly-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693098/how-to-make-doubles-work-properly-c-sharp)

Is there any similar type for Borland C++ Builder programs?

Comment: Intel have a library http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library/ that implements the IEEE 754-2008 Decimal Floating-Point Arithmetic specification

Comment: @dash, The link you provided and the Intel library seems promising. It's worth a try for someone that needs high degree of accuracy.

Comment: Instead of using the outdated Borland C++, can you migrate to C++ .NET and use the System.Decimal? Certainly you can create a small program in .NET given the inputs.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid, I was forced to migrate to .NET :) but I'm very familiar with BCB... I would like to know who wins on that case: .NET Vs. Borland

Comment: @kokbira, Borland is struggling to keep up with Microsoft. Only Linux, PHP, and Apache toolset can compete with Microsoft. I suggest you migrate to .NET asap, and you're forced to anyway. At least, you won't have to deal with this decimal issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `decimal` type in C#, .NET's `System.Decimal` type, is just a floating point number stored as base-10 instead of base-2 encoding. `float` and `double` are more typical base-2 floating point numbers. That is, a `double` is stored as `+/- x * 2^y` while a decimal is stored as `+/- x * 10 ^ y`. That's why it does better for, as one example, financial data, which is typically expressed in terms of `x * 10^-2`. The IEEE standard 754 (the floating point math standard) calls this "decimal floating point" math, and defines a 32- and 64-bit version of each.

In C++, these types are implemented in the `std::decimal` namespace, and are called `std::decimal::decimal32` and `std::decimal::decimal64`, in the `<decimal>` header. If Borland C++ builder has such a type, you will find it there. GNU's C++ library includes this header but, AFAIK it's not actually part of the standard yet, so BCB may not have it. If that's the case, you'll need to use a third-party library. @dash's example of Intel's [Decimal Floating Point](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library/) library is probably the best known such library, though a Google search for `IEEE 754 Decimal` should turn up others if, for some reason, you need them.

Comment: Nice answer +1 for both that and Cthulhu

Comment: @kokbira Michael's Avatar looks to be a picture of the generally all-round nice guy from Lovecraftian fiction sometimes known as Cthulhu. Except he's not very nice.

Answer (score 3):

These are the float types that you can use in Delphi:

```
single  :  4 bytes (32bits)
real    :  6 bytes (48bits)
double  :  8 bytes (64bits)
currency:  8 bytes (64bits) (this is probably what you're looking for)
extended: 10 bytes (80bits) (maps to double when you compile to x64!)
```

In C++ builder there seems to be a `System::Currency` class that mimics Delphi's built in currency type. Maybe it helps to look into that.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know if it uses base-10 to store values? What about the range of `currency` type?

Answer (score 2):

I found this link [Borland C++ Primitive Data types](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3acdHCy__Rpo4J%3ahelpcentreonline.com/article/primitiv_console_bcc.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgfnmX6nsUy1YBnQ9Xrn9soCEjsf7XJ5glWn_pIiRV7x6ZDJ7fU21M-lnQvRpbrdzTJhiPNcQnxtQDZyN45OnOiyRQ18bxqYXsyf6p7VD05twUUk5kTqv4BQbYeJkQA-myz0GaW&sig=AHIEtbT-IT61GLf2cmgOOQiehzWepze60A&pli=1) . View it in HTML.

There is a long double type having capacity of 10 bytes.

The document is informative. You may want to read it anyway.

Comment: Very informative, but I was searching a way to use float point values stored on base-10 instead of on base-2 to see if some calculations on certain programs would become more precise...

Comment: Well, I can have more precise calculations using `long double`, for example, but I would like to evaluate a solution with base-10...

Comment: If I understood Borland's documentation correctly, Borland float and double types use base 10 instead of base 2.