# Why is .NET's Complex type broken?

Tags: c#, .net, complex-numbers

I was astounded to find that the `System.Numerics.Complex` data type in .NET doesn't yield mathematically accurate results.

```
Complex.Sqrt(-1) != Complex.ImaginaryOne
```

Instead of (0, 1), I get (6.12303176911189E-17, 1), which looks a lot like a rounding error.

Now I realize that floating point arithmetic will lead to results like this sometimes, but usually using integers will avoid rounding errors.

Why does this seemingly basic operation yield an obviously wrong result?

Comment: The type isn't broken, no reason for the dramatics.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Well, that's the best word I could find to describe it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Double precision problems on .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/566958/60761) and many others.

Comment: _doesn't yield mathematically accurate results_ - that is true for all fp operators and Math.* methods for most of their input range.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I know that. I know how floating point numbers work. And this is a case where it looks like it should work.

Comment: Well... wrong expectation then. I would never have trusted it.

Comment: Given that Complex.Sqrt(-1) should equal Complex.ImaginaryOne, what is the suggested comparison operation if not an (in)equality check?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the decompiled `Sqrt` method.

```
public static Complex Sqrt(Complex value)
{
    return Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(Math.Sqrt(value.Magnitude), value.Phase / 2.0);
}
```

There is in fact a rounding error caused by using polar coordinates and radians. `value.Phase / 2.0` will return pi/2, which isn't an exactly representable number. When converting from polar coordinates (1, pi/2), the rounding error becomes visible when the real coordinate nears zero.