# ?? Operator (C#) for double returns incorrect result

Tags: c#, null, double, coalescing, null-coalescing

Using C#, any idea why the following method returns **57.999999999999993** (instead of **58**)?

```
double Test_Null_Coalescing_Operator()
{
    double? x = 0.58;
    return ((x ?? 0) * 100);
}

//returns 57.999999999999993 (instead of 58)
```

Comment: Also see [double precision problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566958/double-precision-problems-on-net).

Comment: Use Math.Round.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: This has absolutely noting to do with `??` or `null`. Try to isolate your issues.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming double is IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point, 0.58 is not exactly representable. The closest is 0.57999999999999996003197111349436454474925994873046875. After multiplying by 100, the rounding error on rounding up to 58 would be 3.99680288865056354552507400512695312500E-15, which is slightly bigger than the rounding error on rounding down to 57.99999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875, 3.10862446895043831318616867065429687500E-15

If you are representing physical quantities such as length, the measurement error will completely dwarf the rounding error, less than one part in 10<sup>15</sup>.

There are some special cases, such as some financial calculations, for which exact representation of short terminating decimal fractions is important. For those, you should generally use a decimal type, not double.

Comment: what is the way to avoid this?

Comment: @Jignesh It's an intrinsic property of binary floating point numbers, so you can't really avoid it.  If you don't want it use decimal floating point numbers, i.e. the `decimal` type.

Answer (score 1):

[Rounding error. 0.58 not exists as a double.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)

Answer (score 0):

@Felipe Deveza already mentioned about the reason. If you want to receive exactly 0.58, you can use [Math.Round()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

The answers and the linked [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) explain the reason, I just want to highlight a rule of thumb. Whenever the decimally written representation of the number is relevant use the [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) type instead. The `float` and `double` types are fast as they are directly supported by the CPU but use them only if their decimal representation is not important (eg. rendering, multimedia processing, etc.).

In many languages the `decimal` (or a similar decimal floating-point type for the same purpose) is called *money* suggesting that this is what you should use for financial calculations. And actually that's where the `m` postfix of the `decimal` comes from in C# as well (`var x = 0.58m`).