# Why the result is different for this problem?

Tags: c#, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I came across this following arithmetic problem.

But the result is different from normal maths operation, Why is it so?

```
double d1 = 1.000001;

double d2 = 0.000001;

Console.WriteLine((d1-d2)==1.0);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I presume you found the question on Jon Skeet's Brainteasers page? The answers are listed and explained [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers-answers.html) on the same website.

For a matter of reference, here's the answer copied from that page.

---

**3) Silly arithmetic**

Computers are meant to be good at arithmetic, aren't they? Why does this print "False"?

```
double d1 = 1.000001; double d2 =
0.000001; Console.WriteLine((d1-d2)==1.0);
```

Answer: All the values here are stored as binary floating point. While 1.0 can be stored exactly, 1.000001 is actually stored as
1.0000009999999999177333620536956004798412322998046875, and 0.000001 is actually stored as
0.000000999999999999999954748111825886258685613938723690807819366455078125. The difference between them isn't exactly 1.0, and in fact the difference can't be stored exactly either.

---

Answer (score 3):

From the MSDN entry for [Double.Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485175/c-net-is-it-safe-to-check-floating-point-values-for-equality-to-0/485741):

> **Precision in Comparisons**
>
> The Equals method should be used with
>   caution, because two apparently
>   equivalent values can be unequal due
>   to the differing precision of the two
>   values. The following example reports
>   that the Double value .3333 and the
>   Double returned by dividing 1 by 3 are
>   unequal.
>
> ...
>
> Rather than comparing for equality,
>   one recommended technique involves
>   defining an acceptable margin of
>   difference between two values (such as
>   .01% of one of the values). If the
>   absolute value of the difference
>   between the two values is less than or
>   equal to that margin, the difference
>   is likely to be due to differences in
>   precision and, therefore, the values
>   are likely to be equal. The following
>   example uses this technique to compare
>   .33333 and 1/3, the two Double values
>   that the previous code example found
>   to be unequal.

If you need to do a lot of "equality" comparisons it might be a good idea to write a little helper function or extension method in .NET 3.5 for comparing:

```
public static bool AlmostEquals(this double double1, double double2, double precision)
{
    return (Math.Abs(double1 - double2) <= precision);
}
```

This could be used the following way:

```
double d1 = 1.000001;

double d2 = 0.000001;

bool equals = (d1 - d2).AlmostEquals(1.0, 0.0000001);
```

See this very similar question: [C#.NET: Is it safe to check floating point values for equality to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485175/c-net-is-it-safe-to-check-floating-point-values-for-equality-to-0/485741)

Comment: why the downcast and no comment? +1 to undo the -1. The answer might not be exactly what the user is asking, but it does offer a way to check for these kinds of calculations.

Answer (score 2):

It is because computers do maths in base 2, and hence many decimal floating point numbers can not be represented exactly with a limited number of digits.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using floating point numbers.

http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing such arithmetic in your application, the [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.80).aspx) type should be used

```
decimal d1 = 1.000001M;

decimal d2 = 0.000001M;

Console.WriteLine((d1 - d2) == 1.0M); // evaluates as true
```

Comment: Be careful! decimal also has limited precision. Example: decimal d1 = 1.0M / 3.0M; decimal d2 = 3.0M; (d1 * d2) == 1.0M; // <-- this gives false!

Answer (score 1):

this may be due to floating point precision problems as it could be that your outcome is not exactly 1.0 but maybe something like 1.000000000001

Answer (score 1):

This happens because floating point types store numbers using a base two and not a base ten representation. This has the consequence that double is unable to store values like 0.1 exactly. For example 0.1 is represented by the single value 0.100000001490116119384765625.

You have to use Decimal to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way that floating point numbers work in the CPU, it's not C# specific. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) Wikipedia entry and the paper [here](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more info.

The short answer is that floating point numbers aren't stored as an exact representation, so doing a comparison using "==" doesn't work in the way you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

See what python docs has to saym the problem is the same for both:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html