# Is it wrong to compare a double to 0 like this: doubleVariable==0?

Tags: c#, double

It is ok to do this?

```
double doubleVariable=0.0;
if (doubleVariable==0) {
   ...
}
```

Or this code would suffer from potential rounding problems?

Comment: the rounding problem would only happen if you were trying to get a double result from dividing two integers

Comment: I don't agree with that. if (x=0.1) ... has rounding problems.

Comment: That's because 0.1 does not have an exact representation as a binary floating-point number.  A decimal type may better suit your needs (x=0.1M)

Comment: @Eric: I understand the issue. But I've seen code doing x==0 or x==1 and I wanted to make sure that's fine (for x being a double).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing double values in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/comparing-double-values-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope it's perfectly legal if you are only going to compare against 0 as the right side of comparison will automatically casted to double. On the other hand, it would yield all the round-off errors if you where to compare against == 0.10000001

You are better or reading the discussion about float to 0 comparison here: [Is it safe to check floating point values for equality to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485175/c-net-is-it-safe-to-check-floating-point-values-for-equality-to-0)

Also this discussion is very informative about weird precision problems on floats: [Why the result is different for this problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721002/why-the-result-is-different-for-this-problem)

i.e. below will yield false:

```
double d1 = 1.000001; double d2 =0.000001;
Console.WriteLine((d1-d2)==1.0);
```

Comment: that will obviously yield true. 1.0 is literal and doubleVariable is double so the comparison will return true.

Answer (score 3):

What you have there is `0`, which is an integer literal.  It is implicitly converted to a double which you could represent with the double literal `0.0` ([implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx)).  Then there is a comparison between the two doubles.  A rounding error could cause `doubleVariable` to not be equal to `0.0` (by some other math you might do, not just setting it), but there could never be a rounding error when converting the integer 0 to double.  The code you have there is totally safe, but I would favor `== 0.0` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if (double.Equals(doubleValue, 0.0)){}
```

Comment: This question has been asked three years ago, and your post isn't very detailed. Maybe you can improve your answer by adding details and outlining the solution. Please also take a __[tour]__ and see [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you're just comparing a double variable against 0.0 (or 0), I believe it's safe to do it that way because I think 0 can be represented exactly in floating point, but I'm not 100% sure.

In general, the suggested approach for comparing floating point numbers is to choose a "delta" value at which you'll consider two doubles to be equal if their difference is less than the delta.  This handles exact representation limitations with floating point numbers.

```
double first = 1.234;
double second = 1.2345;
double difference = Math.Abs(first - second);

double threshold = 0.000001; // doubles are equal if their difference is less than this value - you choose this value based on your needs
bool areEqual = difference < threshold;
```

Answer (score 1):

hmm... I think as long as the number has an exact binary fraction representation (like 0) the comparison is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use double for such comparision.
  double creates problem.
e.g `double n1=0.55`  `double n2=100`  then `double ans=n1*n2` should be `55.0`
but when you debug ans is `55.000000000000007`.
`if(ans==55.0)`
will fail. in such case you can face a problem.