# how do I not show the value zero in the chart

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

asp.net + c#

I have a chart within a ItemTemplate
 how do I not show the value zero in the graph for this case?

I did

```
 protected void Chart1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           foreach (Series s in Chart1.Series)
            {
                foreach (DataPoint dp in s.Points)
                {
                    foreach (double val in dp.YValues)
                    {
                        if (val == 0)
                            dp.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But as the chart is inside an ItemTemplate does not work.
How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650091/c-whats-the-best-way-to-compare-double-and-int), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398753/problem-in-comparing-double-values-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658799/is-it-wrong-to-compare-a-double-to-0-like-this-doublevariable-0). They have a lot of information on this.

Comment: In my code behind can not access the id of the control chart, because this is inside an ItemTemplate and turn in a gridview.
Soon the code originally posted by me only works if the chart is not within the ItemTemplate. What can I do?