# Divide by zero return infinite

Tags: c#, divide-by-zero

I'm new to programming and I have a problem with dividing by zero. Problem is explained in comment in code.

```
public float Divide (float a, float b)
{
    if (!Equals (b, 0))
        return a / b;
    else
        return 0; // what should this return contains not to giving me back  infinite?
                  // But for example message that you can't divide by zero?
}
```

Comment: Whatever you want.  Are you asking for exceptions?

Comment: Unrelated note: you should be careful comparing float numbers for equality. Generally, you should never do it, as it is very likely to backfire due to precision issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not be returning 0. You should return `float.NegativeInfinity` (if `a` is negative) or `float.PositiveInfinity` (if `a` is positive), and `float.NaN` if both `a` and `b` are 0. Note that this is the same behavior that you would get if you did this in your code:

```
return a / b;
```

So you might want to simply change your code to read:

```
public float podil (float a, float b) {
    return a / b;
}
```

If dividing by 0 represents a specific illegal condition in your application, and you don't want `float.NaN` values to propagate, you should throw an exception. Like:

```
public float podil (float a, float b) {
    var result = a / b;
    if (float.IsNan(result))
        throw new DivideByZeroException(); // or a different exception type.
    return result;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nbj4Cm), It will return `float.PositiveInfinity`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will throw a `DivideByZero` exception, not return postive/negative infinity

Comment: @BradleyDotNET not for floats; they will return infinity for division by zero (or NaN for 0/0). Integer division will throw a divide by zero exception.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you what to return if you don't like default... Usually one would throw exception, but it is not "return".

Most close answer would be return [nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) `float?` -

```
public float? podil (float a, float b) 
{
    return b == 0 ? (float?) null : a / b;
}
```

You may also consider [`double.PositiveInfinity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.positiveinfinity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but dealing with exceptions or nullable types is generally easier.

Note: be careful with comparing floating point numbers to 0 (either with `Equals` or `==`) due to possible rounding issues in previous computations - [Is it wrong to compare a double to 0 like this: doubleVariable==0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658799/is-it-wrong-to-compare-a-double-to-0-like-this-doublevariable-0))

Answer (score 0):

What is the result you want? An infinite value? There is none for `float`.Don't call the method if `b` is zero unless you want a specific result.

As for your code you could to this (it's just one solution of many): use the built-in infinity constant such as this:

```
public float Divide (float a, float b)
{
    return Equals (b, 0) ? float.NegativeInfinity : a / b;
}
```