# Use of unassigned local variable 'totalroadtax'

Tags: c#, methods, asmx

I'm trying to create a method for my web-service however i receive this error listed in the title

> Use of unassigned local variable 'totalroadtax'

This is how the user have to input 2 different variable to trigger the method in the webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public double RoadTax(int engineCapacity, int vehicleAge)
{
    double totalroadtax;

    if (engineCapacity.Equals("600") && vehicleAge.Equals("12"))
    {
        totalroadtax = ((200.00 * 0.782) * (1.10));
    }

    return totalroadtax;
    //return (engineCapacity - vehicleAge);
}
```

I declared my totalroadtax in my method, input some caluclation method and return the value. I checked the have the necessary information for this method to work but I still receive the error. Did i leave anything out here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `if` may be skipped (if the condition is false) and you're returning `totalroadtax`. The variable is not initialized at that point because you declared it without an initial value.

You should declare the variable with some initial value like:

```
double totalroadtax = 0;
```

**Edit:**

Your code needlessly compares `int` values to `string` literals. It's cleaner and more efficient to perform the condition this way:

```
[WebMethod]
public double RoadTax(int engineCapacity, int vehicleAge)
{
    double totalroadtax = 0;

    if (engineCapacity == 600 && vehicleAge ==12)
    {
        totalroadtax = ((200.00 * 0.782) * (1.10));
    }

    return totalroadtax;
}
```

There's no need to call `Equals()` - the `==` operator reads better and it performs a type-safe check.

I'd also recommend that you don't perform direct equality checks against floating-point values. Instead of using `==`, you should really check for something like:

```
if ( (engineCapacity >599.9999 && engineCapacity < 600.00001) && ...
```

This is because floating-point values are not exact representations of fractional numbers.

Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485175/is-it-safe-to-check-floating-point-values-for-equality-to-0-in-c-net) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

`totalroadtax` is unassigned when `if` condition is not met. Change your declaration to:

```
double totalroadtax = 0d;
```

Comment: Is there any advantage with using `d` literal here?

Comment: @Selman22 No, it just indicates that the literal 0 is of type `double`.

Comment: but i'm not very sure why somehow the value the .asmx returns me is 0 though.

Answer (score 3):

It's good practice to always initialize variables.

In this particular case if the `if` evaluates to `false`, the variable totalroadtax will be returned uninitialized. To fix the issue you need to initialize `totalroadtax`:

```
double totalroadtax = 0d;
```

---

Here is an alternative nicer solution imo, avoiding the variable all together:

```
[WebMethod]
public double RoadTax(int engineCapacity, int vehicleAge)
{
    if (engineCapacity.Equals("600") && vehicleAge.Equals("12"))
    {
        return ((200.00 * 0.782) * (1.10));
    }

    return 0d;
}
```

Comment: i tried and run the webmethod in the .asmx but then it returns me a 0. Could it be possibly due to the `return 0d;`?

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan the `if` condition didn't change so it must be a problem with your condition.

Comment: Also fyi, the `0d` is optional, it just indicates that it's a `double`, not an `int`. This is good practice as it prevents possible casts (in other cases) and communicates the developer's intent.

Comment: However, in my .asmx file, i insert the exact value that i have input in my if else statement and i still receive the return value as 0 though.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to add to previous answers so I'll start off with the obvious: your method does not initialize the variable.

You also mentioned your method also returns 0 every time. Consider this line:

```
engineCapacity.Equals("600") && vehicleAge.Equals("12")
```

Here's why:

In this case, `Equals` will compare a `string` (`"600"`) and an `int` (`engineCapacity` and `vehicleAge`). The `if` condition will fail and return `0`. Compare the values using the `==` equality operator using `int`s, instead.