# Dealing with floating point precision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in unity and have run into a problem when resetting the speed to 0.

The game uses multiple throttle levels: -2 -1 0 1 2. When set to a throttle level the object is meant to speed up to a set speed. This works but when I come to reset it to 0 the speed sets its self to 0.0999999 even though 0 is set.

How can I fix this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class Script_Control : MonoBehaviour {
public static float speedLvL;
public static float speed;
public static float health;
public static float manoverablity;
public static float tarSpeed;
public static float curSpeed;           
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

//setting per ship stats
speedLvL = 0F;
speed = .25F;
health = 25F;
manoverablity = .25F;
//General Stats
tarSpeed = 0F;
curSpeed = 0F;

}

// FixedUpdate is called once per Time
void FixedUpdate () {
    Debug.Log(curSpeed);
//setting speed 
if (speedLvL == 0F){
    tarSpeed = 0.00000F;
}
if (speedLvL == 1F)  {
    tarSpeed = speed/2F;
}
if (speedLvL == 2F)  {
    tarSpeed = speed;
}
if (speedLvL == -1F)  {
    tarSpeed = -speed/5F;
}
if (speedLvL == -2F)  {
    tarSpeed = -speed/2.5F;
}

if (curSpeed < tarSpeed){
    curSpeed += .1F;
}
if (curSpeed > tarSpeed){
    curSpeed -= .1F;
}
    transform.Translate(curSpeed, 0, 0);

}
void Update(){

    if (Input.GetAxis("Throttle") > 0 && speedLvL <= 1 &&  speedLvL >= -2){
        speedLvL = speedLvL+1;      
        DateTime t = DateTime.Now; 
        DateTime tf = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(.25);
        while (t < tf)
        {
            t = DateTime.Now;
        } 
    }   

    if (Input.GetAxis("Throttle") < 0 && speedLvL <= 2 &&  speedLvL >= -1){
        speedLvL = speedLvL-1;
        DateTime t = DateTime.Now; 
        DateTime tf = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(.25);
        while (t < tf)
        {
            t = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Stearing") < 0){
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward* Time.deltaTime, manoverablity );

    }
    if (Input.GetAxis("Stearing") > 0){
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward* Time.deltaTime, -manoverablity);

    }
}



}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FixedUpdate function you set the if statement which resets the speed to 0,

```
if (speedLvL == 0F){
    tarSpeed = 0.00000F;
}
```

however in the same function you have below the functions to either speed up or slow down the ship.

```
if (curSpeed < tarSpeed){
    curSpeed += .1F;
}
```

Looks like to me when you reset the ship to 0 it then adds the .1F on before it stops adjusting

You may need to split that function into 2 separate parts!

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks thats it I was too caught up in the float imprecision I didn't think it could be anything out

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform exact comparisons against floating point values (`float` or `double`) because they have inherent limits to the precision of the value they represent.

When you need to compare floating point values, you must always use a range (above and below) around the target value that you're trying to compare to - this way you can account for the imprecision of floating point storage.

Read this question / answer for more detail: [Is it safe to check floating point values for equality to 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485175/is-it-safe-to-check-floating-point-values-for-equality-to-0-in-c-net)

Comment: In fact, no need for your answer, the link you provided is enough.

Comment: @I4V Yes, I already typed it up in excitement when I searched for it.