# sum of digits of large numbers (10^9)?

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve this particular problem: [Project Euler #16](https://projecteuler.net/problem=16):

> 2^15 = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.
>   What is the sum of the digits of the number 2^1000?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int num;
   cin >> num;
   long double n = pow(2, num);
   cout << fixed << n << endl;
   int sum = 0;
   while(n != 0.0)
   {
      sum = sum + fmod(n, 10);
      n = floor(n/10);
   }
   cout << sum << endl;
}
```

The output when user input is 1000 is:

> ```
> 1181
> ```

However, the internet mentions the correct answer to be `1366` instead of the `1181` I got.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. And don't paste a picture of text, paste the text itself

Comment: check if a double is exactly (not) equal to something will amost never work.

Comment: Don't use floating point maths for these sore of calculations it doesn't have the precision.  You need to make a simple long number class instead.

Comment: You have to check what is the maximum value of `long double` you used. It is `LDBL_MAX` constant in C

Comment: @Sma 2^1000 needs 1000 bits of precision, I doubt his `long double` is that big

Comment: AFAIK, nobody knows how to do this, without calculating 2^1000 and adding up the digits.  That means you need to break the problem down.  First device a method to represent a value that large (since even a `long long unsigned` on most machines won't come close), then devise a way to do the calculation of 2^1000 quickly (e.g. maybe use the fact that ((2^10)^10)^10 is equal to 2^1000) and then add up the digits of the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is **not** about the first calculation:

```
long double n = pow(2, num);
```

as even the regular `double` type ([max: `1.79769e+308`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)) will hold `2^1000 = 1.07151e+301` without any problems especially that this is a base 2 calculation.

Note that your using the `double` versions `pow()`, `fmod()` and `floor()` instead of the `long double` versions `powl()`, `fmodl()` and `floorl()`. But that is as I said **not** the problem and won't change anything.

But the calculation in the while loop will lack in precision and rounding errors. Further never check floating point numbers for (un)equality when doing arithmetics with them, see [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485175/is-it-safe-to-check-floating-point-values-for-equality-to-0) (there are a lot of other discussion and threads in the web about that topic).

**In short:**
I assume that your `fmod()` and `floor()` will lead to precision loss and rounding errors.

---

Here is a working solution ([see at ideone](https://ideone.com/8HucrI)) for your case converting the `double` to a `std::string` and iterating through every character of the string adding that char converted to an integer.

**In short:**
It is just using the initial calculation (just with `double`) and convert that to a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main ()
{
   int num;
   std::cin >> num;
   double n = pow(2, num); /* note I use just double */

   std::string nstr = std::to_string(n);
   const char* nstr_p = nstr.c_str();

   std::cout << std::fixed << nstr << std::endl;
   int sum = 0;
   while (std::isdigit(*nstr_p)) /* number contains dot and fractional (.0000) */
   {
      sum = sum + (*nstr_p - '0'); /* convert character to integer and sum it */
      nstr_p++;
   }
   std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 1366
> ```

Note that the conversion: `(*nstr_p - '0')` assumes an encoding like [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) or others where numbers are incrementing without gaps in their hexadecimal representation.

Comment: Hi @TruthSeek if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a C++ approach using the multi-precision integer arithmetic of GMP (note gmpxx.h).

I prefer integers when possible, and gmp makes working with big integers easy enough.

Like Andre, I created a std::string of the result, and added the digits.

---

Environment:

Ubuntu 15.10, 64 bit, using g++-5 is v5.2.1, on older Dell

---

Code:

```
#include <chrono>
// 'compressed' chrono access --------------vvvvvvv
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock  HRClk_t; // std-chrono-hi-res-clk
typedef HRClk_t::time_point                 Time_t;  // ...-time-point
typedef std::chrono::milliseconds           MS_t;    // std-chrono-milliseconds
typedef std::chrono::microseconds           US_t;    // std-chrono-microseconds
typedef std::chrono::nanoseconds            NS_t;    // std-chrono-nanoseconds
using   namespace std::chrono_literals; // support suffixes like 100ms, 2s, 30us
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

#include <gmpxx.h>  // multiprecision arithmetic:
                    // no rounding errors because mpz_class is integer

class T526_t
{
public:
   T526_t() = default;
   ~T526_t() = default;

   int exec()
      {
         Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();

         mpz_class  N("1"); // initialize multi-precision integer to value 1

         std::string s;
         int i;
         for (i=0; true; ++i) // run forever
         {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << N;              // stream i/o from gmpxx.h
            N = N * 2;            // compute next value

            if(i <= 16) // confirm the first 17 values
            {
               std::cout << "\n"
                         << "  2 ^" << std::setw(3) << i
                         << "  size:" << std::setw(2) << ss.str().size()
                         << "  " << digiComma(ss.str())
                         << "  sum : " << sumOfDigits(ss.str());
            }
            s = ss.str();

            if (1000 == i) break; // enough already
         }

         std::cout << "\n\n"
                   << "  2 ^" << std::setw(5) << i
                   << "  size:" << std::setw(4) << s.size()
                   << "  \n\n" << digiComma(s)
                   << "\n\n  sum-of-digits: " << sumOfDigits(s) << std::endl;

         auto duration_us =
            std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);

         std::cout << "\n\n  duration: "
                   << digiComma(std::to_string(duration_us.count()))
                   << " us" << std::endl;

         return (0);
      }


private: // methods

   size_t sumOfDigits(std::string s)
      {
         size_t retVal = 0;
         for (uint i=0; i<s.size(); ++i)
         {
            retVal += s[i] - '0';
         }
         return retVal;
      }

   std::string digiComma(std::string s)
      {  //vvvvv--sSize must be signed int of sufficient size
         int32_t sSize = static_cast<int32_t>(s.size());
         if (sSize > 3)
            for (int32_t indx = (sSize - 3); indx > 0; indx -= 3)
               s.insert(static_cast<size_t>(indx), 1, ',');
         return(s);
      }


}; // class T526_t


int main(int , char** )
{
   Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();

   int retVal = -1;
   {
      T526_t   t526;
      retVal = t526.exec();
   }

   auto  duration_us =
      std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);

   std::cout << "\n  FINI   " << duration_us.count() << " us" << std::endl;
   return(retVal);
}
```

---

Results:

```
Rule-526: dumy526.cc
rm -f dumy526
g++-5 -m64  -O0 -ggdb -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor
                -pedantic -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith
                -Wunused -Woverloaded-virtual   dumy526.cc  -o dumy526
                -L../../bag  -lbag_i686  -lgmpxx -lgmp

real    0m2.235s
user    0m1.992s
sys 0m0.208s

  2 ^  0  size: 1  1  sum : 1
  2 ^  1  size: 1  2  sum : 2
  2 ^  2  size: 1  4  sum : 4
  2 ^  3  size: 1  8  sum : 8
  2 ^  4  size: 2  16  sum : 7
  2 ^  5  size: 2  32  sum : 5
  2 ^  6  size: 2  64  sum : 10
  2 ^  7  size: 3  128  sum : 11
  2 ^  8  size: 3  256  sum : 13
  2 ^  9  size: 3  512  sum : 8
  2 ^ 10  size: 4  1,024  sum : 7
  2 ^ 11  size: 4  2,048  sum : 14
  2 ^ 12  size: 4  4,096  sum : 19
  2 ^ 13  size: 4  8,192  sum : 20
  2 ^ 14  size: 5  16,384  sum : 22
  2 ^ 15  size: 5  32,768  sum : 26
  2 ^ 16  size: 5  65,536  sum : 25

  2 ^ 1000  size: 302  

10,715,086,071,862,673,209,484,250,490,600,018,105,614,048,117,055,336,074,437,
503,883,703,510,511,249,361,224,931,983,788,156,958,581,275,946,729,175,531,468,
251,871,452,856,923,140,435,984,577,574,698,574,803,934,567,774,824,230,985,421,
074,605,062,371,141,877,954,182,153,046,474,983,581,941,267,398,767,559,165,543,
946,077,062,914,571,196,477,686,542,167,660,429,831,652,624,386,837,205,668,069,
376

  sum-of-digits: 1366


  duration: 4,569 us

  FINI   4616 us
```

---

JFF (just for fun) and because it is easy with the mpz_class:

```
2 ^ 10000  size: 3011  

19,950,631, ... ,596,709,376

sum-of-digits: 13,561



2 ^ 100000  size: 30103  

9,990,020, ... ,883,109,376

sum-of-digits: 135,178
```