# How to avoid rounding/precision errors when dealing with big integers stored in doubles in C++?

Tags: c++, precision

## The problem

I am trying to solve the following:

> 2^15 = 32768 and the sum of its digits is 3 + 2 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 26.
>
> What is the sum of the digits of the number 2^1000?

[Source](https://projecteuler.net/problem=16)

I keep getting false outputs because of precision errors. However, as you can see below, I try to make sure that nothing is rounded, or lost because of precision. The code I wrote falls short of the desired output (1366) by two (1364). How can optimize my code in order to not lose anything else because of precision and rounding errors?

## My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tgmath.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum=0;
    double N = pow(2.0, 1000.0);
    string num = to_string(N);
    for(int i=0; i<num.size(); i++) {
        sum += num[i] - '0';
    }
    cout<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Handle it the same way you would do it using pen and paper. Do addition with carries, do long multiplication, and so on.

Comment: Don't use `double`, use more than one integer. As a simple first cut, use one integer for each digit of the number. Then do long addition (with carries), long multiplication, and so on. Or use a library that already does all this.

Comment: Don't use numbers. Use text. That's what you use use when using pen and paper. Text is good at representing abstract concepts such as numbers.

Comment: What library do you suggest using @DavidSchwartz ?

Comment: Strings work too. You'll have to write functions to do long addition and long multiplication on strings that represent integers in base 10.

Comment: @ripeat OpenSSL has a bignum library, GMP (GNU multiprecision), or (likely best choice) [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html).

Comment: Look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45999579/4944425) by [Andre Kampling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8051589/andre-kampling) in the duplicate Q&A, in particular his [working code](https://ideone.com/8HucrI) which is *similar* to yours. If you notice, the loop is limited to only the digits, because the string will end with something like `".0000"` and that char, `'.'`, would make the sum wrong.

Comment: The "already has an answer" post demo's gmpxx.h (integer) class named 'mpz_class'.

Answer (score 1):

According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E1000) the result of `2^1000` is

```
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
```

That will never fit into an `int` or a `double`. You need to find a library that supports very large numbers. [The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org) is one such library.

Comment: The limits of a 'double' in my environment are 1.79769e+308. Shouldn't 1.07151e+301 (2^1000) be stored in it?

Comment: @ripeat -- *Shouldn't 1.07151e+301 (2^1000) be stored in it?*  -- Not looking like like that.  The answer shows you purely an integer.  There is no floating point involved whatsoever.  I believe this is where you started to go down the wrong track -- the answer requires *integer* or integer-like approaches ( approaches that mimic integer arithmetic), not floating point.