# Is it safe to set a double to a literal and then compare it

Tags: c#, precision

for example

```
double x = -1;
TrySetX(ref x);
if(x == -1)
    //since x == -1, it obviously wasn't set
    TryADifferentWayToSetX(ref x);

Use(x);
```

in the case where x is not changed, will x == -1 always return true, or will I have to use an epsiolon for the comparison?

The logic here is that both literals will presumable be converted to the same value, so there is no need to worry about the fact that they may lose precision.

Comment: wouldn't it have been quicker just to try it for yourself?

Comment: Why do you provide x by ref when you don´t change it?

Comment: @Adyson. i have, and it works. But that might just be a fluke - what about for a different architecture, or a different literal

Comment: Try it again using an irrational number and see what happens.

Comment: How about making `DoSomethingThatMightChangeX` a function that returns a `double?` then check for `x.HasValue` ? As is you are depriving yourself from using the Value -1. Is that reasonable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485175/is-it-safe-to-check-floating-point-values-for-equality-to-0/485741#485741

Comment: @Fildor. perfectly. However since this was in a high performance part of the code, I was hoping to save a byte by avoiding using nullable doubles. However I suppose I could use double.NaN instead

Comment: @HimBromBeere
I was giving an example of a method that may or may not change X, and I want to check afterwards if x was changed, by checking if x equaled -1 - it's original value

Comment: It doesn't matter where you use literal, same literal will produce same value for the same type. Even if you [lose precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398753/1997232), they **both** will do, so comparison will still work.

Comment: @Sinatr
That's what I though. HimBromBeere seems to think differently though. Do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: @YairHalberstadt, I've read his answer several times, but I don't understand what he say (therefore my comment, which I hope is crystal clear). In his code `DoSomething` will be called always if you don't change `x`.

Comment: One pitfall I can think of is using different literals, e.g you may think what `double x = 1 * 0.1` is same as `double x = 100000 * 0.000001`, nope they are different, the latter is `0.099999999999999992`.

Answer (score 0):

Trying it out, it looks like both literals get converted to the same value. As such the comparison is safe:

Here is a little test I wrote

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x = 3.455678756567656765677812345678912345678901234567890123456789009876543223456798765423456709876512345;
        System.Console.WriteLine(x);
        System.Console.WriteLine(x == 3.455678756567656765677812345678912345678901234567890123456789009876543223456798765423456709876512345);
    }
}
```

That number is long enough there will be a large loss in precision, but it prints

```
3.45567875656766
True
```

So indeed there is loss of precision, but the comparison nonetheless works.